# Cannot import python package installed from URL

Tags: pip, setuptools, conda

I tried to install a python package within a `conda` environment using

```
pip install git+https://github.com/lmkoch/logistic-normal.git
```

This seems to work. The package seems to be there according to `conda list` and `pip list`, but when I try to import it, it cannot be found:

```
>>> import logisticnormal
ImportError: No module named logisticnormal
```

I can see the source code in

```
 $ENV/lib/python2.7/site-packages/logisticnormal
```

so I really don't see a reason why it should not be found. Any help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was silly, of course.

I was testing the import using `IPython` and didn't realise that my conda environment (which I created specifically for testing all of this) didn't come with ipython - so I was using the system's ipython which didn't know about the installed package.

To diagnose this, I ran

```
(venv)$ ipython
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['/usr/bin','/usr/lib/python2.7', etc]
```

And to fix it I ran

```
(venv)$ pip install ipython
(venv)$ ipython
>>> import sys
>>> print sys.path
['ENV/bin', 'ENV/lib/python2.7', etc]
>>> import logisticnormal
```

Comment: [feel free to accept your own answer.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)